# Faster method to convert byte array to Hex

Tags: java

There are several ways to convert a byte array to Hex. However, when the array is large, efficiency matters here. Thus, do you think using libraries like `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex` would be faster? Is there a way that has been proven to be more efficient than others?

Thank you :)

Comment: "*Thus, do you think using libraries like `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex` would be faster?*" would be faster than what?

Comment: You can just try it. Here's [how](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9655181/544983